# Proving NP-Completeness of a problem

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, reduction

We are given a set A = {a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>}

Given subsets of A named B<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>, ..., B<sub>m</sub>. If a subset of A named H has intersection with all given B's, we call H "Covering subset". Is there any "covering subset" of size K (cardinality of H is K) for given A and Bs?  Prove that this problem is NP-Complete.

We should reduce some known problem to "covering subset" problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a homework help site. Consider rewording your question and explain what you're confused about.

Comment: This belongs to programmers.stackexchange.com anyways

Comment: @Yuliy: actually, many times, it is. And there's nothing wrong with that. Of course, the OP has shown no effort put into the solution, so I can't see anyone helping him.

Comment: @David I agree that OP has shown little effort himself, but that doesn't usually stop people from posting answers :)  (if problem is simple, at least)

Comment: @chx What PSE has to do with CS and algorithms?

Comment: @Nikita: you're just a good Samaritan, better than me that's for sure! :)

Comment: @David Nah, I just have 2 weeks before starting on a new job and little to occupy myself :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is NOT my homework, i'm studying CLRS myself for some competitions, By the way, i didn't know that i should provide my own answer as well.

Comment: Might have better luck on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

**update**  This is called a [hitting set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_set#Vertex_cover_in_hypergraphs). You can read the same answer in wikipedia article.

This problem is, in a way, dual to [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

We'll change some terminology. Let `{B1, B2, ...}` be elements and `{a1, a2, ...}` be sets. 'Set' `ai` contains 'element' `Bj` in a new problem if set `Bj` contains `ai` in original problem.

Now, you just need to select minimum number of 'sets' `ai` covering all 'elements' `Bj`. And that problem is NP-complete, as shown in the link above.

To clarify the transformation, one problem definition can be produced from another just by replacing set/element and contains/contained. Compare following

*Every set `Bj` contains some selected element `ai`*
*Every 'element' `Bj` is contained by some selected 'set' `ai`*